# Mailgun inbound route 403

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I am trying to test a POST request on Mailgun using `Send A Sample POST` on the routes page, but for some reason when I make a POST request using this, my server returns a 403 response code (or so Mailgun says).

When I POST to my endpoint using cURL or Postman I get a response code of 200 and I can see the payload sent, however Mailgun returns 403 and an empty array.

I am using Laravel on my backend and I have set `VerifyCsrfToken` to ignore the endpoint so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not a lot of information to go on here, can you tell us what you are using for mailgun, API vs SMTP, also have a look in your laravel log, and maybe post the code you are using to send the email?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually trying to RECEIVE mail via Mailgun. I just have a route (/inbound) where I just print the Request variable. When Mailgun posts to it the Request is empty but when I post to it myself I see the data I sent. Though, Mailgun is actually sending post data, it seems empty.

Comment: Is there anything in the apache error logs?

Comment: There's nothing. No errors at all. It's very strange. I can see the Mailgun has hit the page correctly because I can see the server response ("hit!") in the Mailgun logs but the Payload is empty and receives a 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and it turned out Comodo WAF was blocking the request.

Apache error log:

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match
> "<body\\b.{0,}?\\bbackground\\b" at ARGS:stripped-html. [file
> "/usr/local/cwaf/rules/07_XSS_XSS.conf"] [line "50"] [id "212300"]
> [rev "2"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Attack|